# How to Combine Two Animations with Different Y Locations

Tags: animation, armature, transforms

I know how to splice together animations if they both start/end on the same point. But this is a little different.

Animation A - Starts at Y 0m, and ends at around Y 2m (this isn't reflected in the Transform tab)

Animation B - Starts and ends at Y 0m

I spliced the animations together, and tried moving Animation B forward to Y 2m where it needs to be using the Transform tab, but it moved Animation A forward as well, which I don't want.

I then loaded up Animation B by itself and moved it forward to Y 2m and saved it. I then tried to combine it with Animation A again, but it once again moved Animation A forward.

How can I get Animation B on Y 2m without pushing Animation A forward so that A and B merge like they're supposed to?

Comment: are you talking about an armature with bones?

Comment: Yep. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you want animation A to go from point Y = 0 to Y = 1 from frame 0 to 19, and animation B to stay at point Y = 1 from frame 20 to 40.

- You could ***parent your object to an empty*** that will stay still from 0 to 19, then at frame 20 move at Y = 1.
- If you're talking about an armature, in *Object* mode, you could **keyframe the object** at frame 0 and 19, then at frame 20, keyframe it at Y = 1 so that it corrects the animation B location.
- Again for an armature move animation B's ***root's location*** (+ 1 to Y location) or its ***bones locations*** (in the *Graph Editor* select the Y location curve and give it +1).
- And you could do it with the ***Delta Transform*** values:

Open the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Transform* > *Delta Transform* > *Delta Location*. You will tweak these values in order to change the object's 0 global location.

At frame 0 create a keyframe with X/Y/Z = 0/0/0. Duplicate this keyframe and put it at frame 19.

At frame 20 create a keyframe with X/Y/Z = 0/1/0.

When your object will arrive at frame 20, animation B begins and it should come back to 0, but the *Delta Transform* forces it to go to Y = 1. Therefore you won't see the object jump back to 0.

[image]

You can fix your particular case with the root's position. As you didn't change its position it would still make your armature position move whatever you do, so:

- First your armature and animation are super messy, but let's ignore this. Find your root bone, you can find it in the *Outliner*, it's called *b_C_Base*, select it in the *Outliner*, switch your armature to *Edit* mode:

[image]

- It's a very small bone so you can't see it, scale it. Now switch to *Pose* mode. You can see its position on the Z armature local position at frame 90, copy it.

[image]

- Go to frame 116, when the animation is supposed to stop, you can see that the bone is set to back to its 0 position.

[image]

- Paste the Z position you've copied, it will move the whole armature to the good position. Create a keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd>, it works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked with the cube as you instructed. But with my animations the second one still pushes the first one forward no matter what I try.

Comment: maybe share your file or a file with a similar situation: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It probably wouldn't be a good idea for me to upload it onto blend-exchange, but I can give you a MediaFire link to the zip folder I shared with a fellow on Upwork if you want to take a look at everything. I'm not sure he really understands what I need him to do, maybe you'd have better luck. The link is: http://www.mediafire.com/file/srq743vdzu7541v/Animation_Folder.zip/file

Comment: Ok check my answer, actually you didn't really tried what I said, you need to fix the root bone (third point of my initial answer)    :)

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thank you. You've been a big help. :)